# numero de combinaciones de una lista

Tags: java

tengo un programa que halla todas las combinaciones de `k` elementos de una lista. Pero cuando son muchos elementos tarda un rato en arrojar el resultado y queria poner un progress bar para que el usuario sepa el tiempo que falta para acabar el proceso. Para ello necesito saber en cada momento qué combinacion se esta calculando. Para ello utilizo la variable `numerodecombinaciones` que se deberia incrementar cada vez que se calcule una combinacion nueva. Pero no encuentro el sitio donde ponerla. En el codigo la tengo en medio de la funcion recursiva (`findCombinations`) que se utiliza para obtener las combinaciones, pero no me coincide el valor de la variable `numerodecombinaciones` con el numero de combinaciones obtenidas. ¿donde deberia incrementar la variable `numerodecombinaciones` para que me coincidiese con las combinaciones obtenidas?
p.d: el numero de combinaciones obtenidas con el codigo de abajo es 17, pero el numero de combinaciones obtenida es 10.

```
public class RepartirCantidades2 {
    
    public static int[] A = {1,2,3,4,5};
    public static int k = 3;
    public static int numerodecombinaciones=0;
    public static List<List<Integer>> combinaciones = new ArrayList();
    
    public static void findCombinations(int[] A, int i, int k,
                                        Set<List<Integer>> subarrays,
                                        List<Integer> out)
            
            
    {
        // entrada inválida
        if (A.length == 0 || k > A.length) {
            return;
        }
 
        // caso base: el tamaño de la combinación es `k`
        if (k == 0) {
            subarrays.add(new ArrayList<>(out));
            return;
        }
        numerodecombinaciones++;
        // comienza desde el siguiente índice hasta el último índice
        for (int j = i; j < A.length; j++)
        {
            // agrega el elemento actual `A[j]` a la solución y repite para el siguiente índice
            // `j+1` con un elemento menos `k-1`
            
            out.add(A[j]);
            findCombinations(A, j + 1, k - 1, subarrays, out);
            out.remove(out.size() - 1);        // retractarse
            
        }
    }
    
public static Set<List<Integer>> findCombinations(int[] A, int k)
    {
        numerodecombinaciones++;
        Set<List<Integer>> subarrays = new HashSet<>();
        findCombinations(A, 0, k, subarrays, new ArrayList<>());
        combinaciones.addAll(subarrays);
        return subarrays;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        findCombinations(A,k);
        System.out.println(combinaciones); 
        System.out.println(numerodecombinaciones);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la llamada a la función ya cuentas una combinación y no sabes si puede que tenga una condición no valida (comprobadas en el primer if)

Por otro lado tienes que poner el sumatorio en la única condición valida de salida de la función, cuando se cumple el caso base y queda de la siguiente forma:

```
public class RepartirCantidades2 {

    public static int[] A = {1,2,3,4,5};
    public static int k = 3;
    public static int numerodecombinaciones=0;
    public static List<List<Integer>> combinaciones = new ArrayList();

    public static void findCombinations(int[] A, int i, int k,
                                    Set<List<Integer>> subarrays,
                                    List<Integer> out)
        
        
    {
        // entrada inválida
        if (A.length == 0 || k > A.length) {
            return;
        }
     
        // caso base: el tamaño de la combinación es `k`
        if (k == 0) {
            subarrays.add(new ArrayList<>(out));
            numerodecombinaciones++;
            return;
        }
    
        // comienza desde el siguiente índice hasta el último índice
        for (int j = i; j < A.length; j++)
        {
                    
            out.add(A[j]);
            findCombinations(A, j + 1, k - 1, subarrays, out);
            out.remove(out.size() - 1);        // retractarse
        
        }
    }

    public static Set<List<Integer>> findCombinations(int[] A, int k)
    {
    
        Set<List<Integer>> subarrays = new HashSet<>();
        findCombinations(A, 0, k, subarrays, new ArrayList<>());
        combinaciones.addAll(subarrays);
        return subarrays;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        findCombinations(A,k);
        System.out.println(combinaciones); 
        System.out.println(numerodecombinaciones);
    }
}
```

Comment: perfecto, me funciono. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Me alegro que te ayudara